# Reflection of sky on car in Opengl es 2 in iphone/ ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, reflection, opengl-es-2.0

Started working on car racing game with Opengl-es 2.0 ... Wandering how to show reflection of sky, trees ,etc  on a car while its moving ... i have seen many games doing so... please guide me where to start from ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "environment mapping". See [this](http://gamesfromwithin.com/environment-mapping-demo-with-opengl-es-1-1).

Comment: Hey any idea on creating shadows of objects in opengl-ES 1.1 ?